# is watching hentai haram?(no sounds )

Tags: halal-haram, pornography

i believe its OK because its not real and unreal drawings and that it doesn't make me want to commit zinah.
i have read somewhere it is haram if it makes you want to commit zinah
is that right and is it OK to watch hentai and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

The Quranic verse 17:32 is giving clear command on that.

> 32.And **do not approach** unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way.
>
> <sup>[Sura Al-Isra (17)](https://legacy.quran.com/17/32)</sup>

If you pay attention, Allah is saying **"do not approach"**. He is not saying **"do not do"**.

Watching those anime films defenitely qualifies to be the act of **"approach"**. It means that one is taking initial steps towards real act of Zina.

Your claim that **"its not real and unreal drawings and that it doesn't make me want to commit zinah"** is nothing but justification of this act of **"approach"**.